# Converting CLI array to std::string without for-cycle

Tags: arrays, string, c++-cli, clr

I want to convert `array<unsigned char>^` to `std::string`. Is it possible to do the conversion **without iterating** over the array and assigning each character in string?

This is my "best" solution (and I don't like the assigning in for-cycle):

```
std::string CliArray2String(array<unsigned char>^ aSource)
{
    std::string strResult("");
    if (aSource != nullptr)
    {
        int iLength = aSource->GetLength(0);
        strResult.reserve(iLength + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < iLength; i++)
            strResult[i] = aSource[i];
    }
    return strResult;
}
```

Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: `std::string` or `std::wstring`?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you declare `strResult` as a narrow-character string, but the return type is a wide-character string.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `std::string`.

Comment: Use pin_ptr http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx

Comment: This is a non-trivial and lossy conversion, you cannot cram a Unicode codepoint into a byte.  That for-loop is going to be *somewhere*, doesn't much matter where.  You can pretend it doesn't exist with Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi() for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[string range constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)**, and **[pin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx)** the managed array.

```
pin_ptr<unsigned char> p = &aSource[0];
unsigned char *unmanagedP = p;
std::string str(unmanagedP , unmanagedP + aSource->GetLength(0));
```

or the sequence constructor:

```
std::string str(unmanagedP , aSource->GetLength(0));
```

Comment: That still iterates, but at least it doesn't look like it is.  The answer to the original question is, of course, "no."